# How to clone / copy a control (with child controls) using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, clone, dynamic-controls

I've tried a few different solutions found on here and elsewhere on the web without luck so far. Maybe one of you knowledgeable lot might be able to help...

I have a bunch of dynamically created controls by the user which I'm storing as a control collection in the session state so I can display them on every postback.

Each control that the user generates is a div with other controls inside it.

I have a button on each control that will allow the user to either delete the control or duplicate it.

When the user hits "Duplicate" I am calling my web method which handles the event.

When my web method finds the control to be duplicated, I want to make a copy of that control and add it to the page (another function deals with saving it to the control collection (on page_Unload)

```
 Dim DupCtrl As Control = Nothing

        Dim int As Integer = myDynControls.Count
        For i = 0 To int - 1

            If myDynControls(i).ID.Contains(ctrlID) Then
                DupCtrl = Clone_Control(myDynControls(i))
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
End Function
```

And the Clone_Control function :

```
Public Shared Function Clone_Control(OriginalControl As Object) As Object

    Dim type As Type = OriginalControl.[GetType]()
    Dim properties As Reflection.PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties()
    Dim retObject As [Object] = type.InvokeMember("", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, Nothing, OriginalControl, Nothing)
    For Each propertyInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo In properties
        If propertyInfo.CanWrite Then
            propertyInfo.SetValue(retObject, propertyInfo.GetValue(OriginalControl, Nothing), Nothing)
        End If
    Next
    Return retObject
End Function
```

Unfortunately; the line that starts PropertyInfo.SetValue....
always errors with :

```
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
```

and when I look at the InnerException:

```
"Cannot get inner content of dynDiv_FormCtrl_Wrapper_10432 because the contents are not literal."
```

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction to get this working ?

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand clearly your requirment, but if you can do this in client side then jquery clone method would be a good pick.

The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes.

For more info [Jquery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I really need to do this via my web method.  
I can't believe it's so difficult to simply make a clone of a control !